# Is 'individualistic' an absolute term

Tags: word-usage

Would it be correct to label someone as very individualistic.

I know that 'very unique' is grammatically incorrect as 'unique' is an absolute. There are no degrees of being unique. You either are or not.
I was wondering if the same went for 'individualistic'.

Comment: It is generally regarded as bad manners to label people.

Comment: Are you implying that only absolute terms may be used to label people? What do you mean by *an absolute term* anyway?

Comment: maybe you mean "Can I use *very* with *individualistic*?"

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it's considered a relative term, so phrases like "very individualistic" and "most individualistic" are perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Agree:  *individualist* is similar to *independent* ("an independent thinker") which is on the continuum between "needs others" to "hermit".